# Cordova async + promise

Tags: android, ios, cordova, async-await, es6-promise

I'd like to ask if is it possible to run promises and async functions on cordova webview on both Android and iOS platforms? I used [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com) to check browser support. What version of browser is used by Cordova for iOS? I installed es6-promise-plugin so I'm not worried about promises that much.

About async and it's support by device/version at iOS/Android. What is minimal version?

Thank you.